# MySql Сount по месяцам

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида:

ID date

Как сделать запрос чтобы результатом стала таблица вида:

Id Jan Feb .... Dec

1   5      3   ....   9

2 ....

Можно искать по отдельному месяцу функцей month, но только по одному за раз, а хотелось сразу все.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, month(your_date) as mo FROM table GROUP BY month(your_date)

Comment: Похоже, но не совсем то - в этом варианте месяцы сгрупированы в строки, мне же хотелось, чтобы это были отдельные столбцы

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date)=1 THEN 1 END) Jan, COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date)=2 THEN 1 END) Feb, ...`... можно и SUM(). А для 8+ версии - использовать оконные функции.